# Instantiation of date in Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: date, adobe, designer, livecycle

I use Adobe LiveCycle for making PDF reports into a J2EE webapp.

I need to write the time of creation of document (hour and minutes). I tried 2 systems:

- **Java - side**: I use this code:

> return new
>   SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

And, with a *floating text* in the Adobe Lifecycle, the printed time is **12:09** (correct)

- **Adobe - side**: I use this code:

> Date data = new Date();

in a internal *JavaScript* into document and, with a **floating text** in the Adobe LiveCycle, the printed time is **10:09** (uncorrect).

I see a difference of time of 2 hours. Why this difference?

Comment: Do the browser and server shows same time ?

Comment: Yes, I'm working in localhost and I see this error